# How to add a proxy to NSURLSession in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin, nsurlsession

I need to load the content of the webview using a proxy.
I have this code (Objective-C):

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
configuration.connectionProxyDictionary = @{ (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost: [proxyURL host], (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort: [proxyURL port] };
```

The following Xamarin code doesn't work, ConnectionProxyDictionary is set but application doesn't use this settings:

```
var configuration = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;
configuration.ConnectionProxyDictionary = new NSDictionary("kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost", proxyURL.Host, "kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort", proxyURL.port);
```

How to port above Objective-C code to Xamarin.iOS? Is there another way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because in Objective-C, the kXX is replaced with an actual reference to a constant, and in C#, you just plugged a string name.

You need to fetch the value of that constant and pass it:

Use this:

```
 using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
 ...

 var keyHost = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant ("kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost")
 var keyPort = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant ("kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort")
```

Then use keyHost and keyPort as your parameters in the NSDictionary

Comment: Thanks. GetStringConstant has two parameters: public static NSString GetStringConstant(IntPtr handle, string symbol);

Comment: How to get the first parameter in this case? I assume that dlopen (string path, int mode) is the answer, but I do not understand what is "path" in my case and what is right value for "mode"?

Comment: This works: Dlfcn.dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork", 0);

Answer (score 0):

```
var configuration = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;                  
NSObject[] values = new NSObject[]
{
    NSObject.FromObject(proxyURL.host),     //ProxyHost
    NSNumber.FromInt32 (proxyURL.port),     //Port
    NSNumber.FromInt32 (1),                   //Enable HTTP proxy

};

NSObject[] keys = new NSObject[]
{
    NSObject.FromObject("HTTPProxy"),
    NSObject.FromObject("HTTPPort"),
    NSObject.FromObject("HTTPEnable")
};

NSDictionary proxyDict = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys (values, keys);
configuration.ConnectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict;

var session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration (configuration);
var task = session.CreateDataTask(NSUrl.FromString("http://google.com"));
task.Resume ();
```

Comment: Provided code might help, but in order to make it a good answer you should also describe/explain why/how exactly does your code solve the problem.